# how can I pass parameters to the reportSource that on the web api service

Tags: telerik, reporting, reportviewer, asp.net-web-api, telerik-reporting

Reports: Report Library

RepoerViewer: Html5

ReportService: Web Api

in Web api services, dataSource brings 32,000 rows of data. but only 10 rows of data used in the report. In this way, very slow reporting. How can I pass parameters to the web api service?

ReportViewer:

```
<div id="reportViewer1" class="k-widget">
    loading...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#reportViewer1")
        .telerik_ReportViewer({
            serviceUrl: "http://localhost:2404/api/StokPaketList/",
            templateUrl: '../ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html',
            reportSource: {
                report: "BeeSp.ReportLibrary.Stok.RprStokPaket, BeeSp.ReportLibrary",
                parameters: {
                    CultureID: "en"
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Report Web Api Service:

```
class CustomReportResolverWithFallBack : IReportResolver
{
    readonly IReportResolver _parentResolver; private IStokPaketService _stokPaketService;
    public CustomReportResolverWithFallBack(IReportResolver parentResolver, IStokPaketService stokPaketService)
    {
        this._parentResolver = parentResolver;
        _stokPaketService = stokPaketService;
    }
    public ReportSource Resolve(string report)
    {
        var reportDocument = this.CustomReportResolver(report);
        if (null == reportDocument
           && null != this._parentResolver)
        {
            reportDocument = this._parentResolver.Resolve(report);
        }
        return reportDocument;
    }
    public ReportSource CustomReportResolver(string report)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType(report);
        var reportInstance = (Report)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        //in this case, report data source brings 32,000 rows of data
        var reportData = _stokPaketService.GetCStokPakets("GOLF").ToList();
        var objectDataSouce = new ObjectDataSource { DataSource = reportData }; 
        reportInstance.DataSource = objectDataSouce;
        return reportInstance;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for posting this question a lots of help

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming there is a better way to do this but what I do is put all parameters into the `reportSource.report` parameter by creating a serialzed JSON object. Then in the `CustomerReportResolver()` method I deserialize the object using the Newtonsoft.Json library. So something like the following:

```
var json = {};
json.reportType = "BeeSp.ReportLibrary.Stok.RprStokPaket, BeeSp.ReportLibrary";
json.rows = 10;

$("#reportViewer1")
    .telerik_ReportViewer({
        serviceUrl: "http://localhost:2404/api/StokPaketList/",
        templateUrl: '../ReportViewer/templates/telerikReportViewerTemplate.html',
        reportSource: {
            report: JSON.stringify(json),
            parameters: {
                CultureID: "en"
            }
        }
    });
```

and then on the server side:

```
public ReportSource CustomReportResolver(string report)
{
    JToken token = JObject.Parse(report);

    int rows = (int)token["rows"];
    string reportType = (string)token["reportType"];
}
```

Then on the data source object you can add the rows parameter as you would any other parameter.

Comment: thanks alot this work for me i spent whole day for this issue but at the end found your answer if it is possible to double vote i will give all votes to you